# Struggling with AWS S3 storage

Tags: python-3.x, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to store and retrieve media images on AWS S3 from a Django based website.
I'm able to view images from and save them to S3 when I'm on localhost, everything works well.
However, when the app is deployed and the website is running live on the internet,
[actual link:](https://django-images-practice.vercel.app/) I'm only able to view the images that are on S3, but NOT able to save images to S3 bucket.
The AWS S3 bucket has full public access. I get the following error while trying to save images to S3:

**Error**

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/suuaY.png)

```
ClientError at /
An error occurred (400) when calling the HeadObject operation: Bad Request
```

It highlights this line of my code:
form_instance.save()

**My code:**
(views.py)

```
def make_and_see(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form_instance = ProductForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form_instance.is_valid():
            form_instance.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Picture is saved')
            return redirect('home')
        else:
            messages.error(request, form_instance.errors)
            return redirect('home')
    else:
        context = {'data': Product.objects.all().order_by('?').first(), 'my_form': ProductForm(), 'time': timezone.now}
        return render(request, 'app1/home.html', context)
```

(settings.py)

```
STORAGES = {"default": {"BACKEND": "storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage"},
            "staticfiles": {"BACKEND": "storages.backends.s3boto3.S3StaticStorage"}}

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = os.environ["MY_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID"]
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = os.environ["MY_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"]
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = '****'
AWS_S3_REGION_NAME = 'ap-south-1'
AWS_QUERYSTRING_AUTH = False
AWS_DEFAULT_ACL = None
AWS_S3_FILE_OVERWRITE = False
AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = f"{AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME}.s3.amazonaws.com"
```

My webite is hosted on Vercel via Github, the Postgresql db hosted on Railway. Any input would be of much help, please. Tried adding the AWS region name to the code: AWS_S3_REGION_NAME, but nothing changed.

Answer (score 1):

Given the fact that you can read the images, but can't write the images it means that the public access to your bucket is working, but there is something wrong with the permissions of the client.

The 400 status code (client error) means something went wrong during the request.

To be able to write to a bucket you will need to make sure you've set the correct permissions. In most cases this happens via AWS IAM and is related to the role or user related to the access key and access secret.

From the above error message I would suggest a couple of things:

1. Make sure that the region you specify in the client is similar to the region in which you made the bucket
2. Validate your IAM permissions for the role / user that belongs to that access key and access secret.
3. Make sure your access key and access secret did not expire. It could be that you've used short lived credentials
4. Make sure you're trying to write to the correct path (bucket)